# Remove assosiation instead of destroying object when :allow_destroy => true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, nested-attributes

When using the new `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in ActiveRecord, it's possible to use the option `:allow_destroy => true`. When this option is set, any hash containing nested attributes like `{"_delete"=>"1", "id"=>"..."}` passed to `update_attributes` will delete the nested object.

Simple setup:

```
class Forum < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users, :allow_destroy => true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :forum
end

Forum.first.update_attributes("users_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"_delete"=>"1", "id"=>"42"}})
```

**Question:** How do I - instead of deleting the nested objects when `"_delete" => "1"` - just remove the association? (i.e. In the above case set the forum_id on the user to nil)

**Bonus question:** What if I also want to change the an attribute on the nested object when removing the association? (e.g. like setting a state or a timestamp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of asking for the user to be deleted using `"_delete" => '1'`, can you not just update it using the nested_attributes?:

```
Forum.first.update_attributes("users_attributes"=> { 
  "0" => {
    "id" => "42",
    "forum_id" => "",
    "state" => 'removed'
  }
})
```